# Create a PDF with non-embedded base fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf, embedding

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdf#Fonts):

> Times, Courier, Helvetica, Symbol, and Zapf Dingbats... or suitable substitute fonts with the same metrics, must always be available in all PDF readers and so need not be embedded in a PDF.

How can I produce a PDF with TeX-world tools, that uses these fonts without embedding them? I want to try out how they look in different PDF viewers. For example, I know of some free software viewers that substitute the Liberation family.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern TeX systems updmap creates an accompanying map file which doesn't download the standard fonts. You can load it instead of pdftex.map like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{pdftex_ndl14.map}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```