# Production of pdf without embedded fonts

Tags: fonts, pdf

PDF files are often used for documentation on linux computers.  To minimize the size of the files, it is great if system fonts can be used.  A package to remove fonts is [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF).  Is this the best way to remove fonts, or can one generate the pdf file without embedding the fonts when starting from LaTex source files?  For LuaLaTeX with OpenType fonts, it seems care is required [Generating PDF files with OpenType math fonts and no font embedding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526450/generating-pdf-files-with-opentype-math-fonts-and-no-font-embedding) but it is unclear if this generalizes to other fonts, such as Computer Modern fonts.

Comment: the map files specify whether or not to embed for pdflatex

Comment: Thanks. Basic info https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129607/create-a-pdf-with-non-embedded-base-fonts, more detail https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/updmap.html

Comment: computer modern is not a system font, and if it is not embedded it will get replaced by some other font which can or can not match.

Comment: Even if computer modern is available on the system?

Comment: @sbkm what do you mean by "available on the system" If you mean installed with tex on the system that won't work, the reading system would have had to install the font system wide

Comment: It would be available system wide, one can specify a dependency on a font package for example on Ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/fonts-cmu and in Fedora https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/texlive/texlive-cm/

Comment: I don't do it very often but if I do want to create a pdf from latex without embedded fonts, I'll use `latex` rather than xe/pdf/lua/latex to create a dvi, convert the dvi to ps with `dvips`, then convert the ps to pdf with `ps2pdf -dEmbedAllFonts=false filename.ps`, then delete the dvi and ps files. No clue if that's the best or preferred way to do it.